# java how can I get all elements name from a xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm new to xml. I'd like to get all the element name from a xml file with xml dom parser, for example the xml file is,
(element's name is dynamic)

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
    <id/>
    <name/>
  <bbb>
  <bbb>
    <id/>
    <name/>
  <bbb>
  <ccc>
    <time/>
    <date/>
  </ccc>
   ....
</aaa>
```

and I want to create a list like this;

aaa,bbb,id,name,ccc,time,date

How can I do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: try this : http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/DOMElements.shtml

Comment: Why are you using XML if you just want a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the popular APIs such as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org) or [Xom](http://www.xom.nu).

The Xom tutorial has an example that does something very similar to what you want.
http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml#Navigator